# How do I convert Python docstrings to a different style?

Tags: python, converters, docstring

I am working on a codebase which uses [Google style Python](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html#example-google) docstrings, and I would like to convert them *automagically* to [numpy style](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_numpy.html).

Is there an automatic tool for doing so?

A quick Google search reveals [pyment](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment), but I'm not sure if that's appropriate.

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question with pyment. Hvae you tried it? Did it not do what you wanted? https://github.com/dadadel/pyment/blob/master/doc/sphinx/source/pyment.rst#what-are-the-supported-formats

Comment: I was wondering if anyone has experience using it on a large codebase. Are you happy with the results?

Comment: But why not just clone the code base, use it, and see for yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyment` definitely looks like the tool for the job as it states it can convert between numpydoc and google docstrings in both directions.

> Currently, the managed styles in input/output are javadoc, one variant of reST (re-Structured Text, used by Sphinx), numpydoc, google docstrings, groups (other grouped style).

Comment: @SewerynNiemiec now Pyment support type hints (at least in the v0.4.0 version, soon available on Pypi)